# Are afterburners required to be engaged during catapult launch?

Tags: aircraft-carrier, afterburner

Is it required to engage afterburners during catapult launches from an aircraft carrier?

[This](http://qr.ae/TU1Fh1) answer mentions that afterburners are used for night takeoffs as per regulations, but not required during day takeoffs. Is this true? If yes, why?

Comment: I think this is a big "it depends". Not all aircraft types have afterburners. For those that do, it might depend on things like takeoff weight or other factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is very much "no" -- afterburners are not at all required to launch from an aircraft carrier.  Longer answer: Fred Larson's comment is correct: it really depends.  Ultimately a given aircraft, at a given weight, with a given wind-over-the-deck, and a few other things, requires ***a given amount of thrust*** to get airborne -- whether it comes from dry thrust or afterburner doesn't change the requirement.

There are a large number of carrier-based aircraft (the [A-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTV_A-7_Corsair_II), [A-6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_A-6_Intruder), and [E-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_E-2_Hawkeye) leap immediately to mind) and there are certainly others that flew off-deck without afterburners.

Current aircraft like the [F/A-18 Hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet) can be launched without afterburner in some, but not all, configurations.  For the most part the incremental safety margin and increased take-off weight means that afterburners are used for takeoff, but it's not strictly a requirement.

Comment: Also, the C-2 Greyhound Carrier Onboard Delivery aircraft is a turboprop - no afterburners there, either.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the aircraft type, loadout, fuel aboard, required endspeed, weather and winds, etc.  Some jet aircraft or carriers e.g. the S3 Viking, A-6/EA-6B, A-7 etc.  did not use engines equipped with re-heat, so that was not an option.   Earlier incarnations of the F-14 required the use of reheat during cat launches due to the low thrust and temperamental nature of the older TF-30 engines; when the GE F-110 powered F-14B and D variants arrived on ship they allowed for launch without the use of afterburning for most load outs and mission profiles as the newer F-110 engines had a max dry thrust on par with the TF-30’s downrated afterburning power output!  The F-404 and F-414 have been solid and reliable power plants for the F-18 series fighters and usually don’t require the use of reheat for light loadouts.   Again the flight crew will have to make that decision based on the factors described above.